# Log pyspark ALS model into mlflow registry

Tags: pyspark, mlflow, als

I am working in pyspark ALS model fitting, and I would like to log and register the model into the MLFlow registry. Since the ALS involves a lot of metadata (part-00.. files) takes too long time to register. I tried to increase the `await_registration_for` paramater. The model registration requires almost 20 minutes to complete the process, which is not efficient for our task.
Is there any ideas how to overcome this challenge, by reducing the size of the ALS model?